# SQL: NOT IN doesn't return expected rows

Tags: mysql, sql, notin

I have table **A**

**A**

```
+--------+------+
| values | data |
+--------+------+
| 11     | 4    |
+--------+------+
| 22     | 5    |
+--------+------+
| 33     | qwe  |
+--------+------+
| 44     | 7    |
+--------+------+
| 55     | zui  |
+--------+------+
```

and this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE data NOT IN (4,5,7)
```

So the expected result is

```
33
55
```

because `qwe` and `zui` are **`NOT IN`** `(4,5,7)`.

But the result is empty. No rows are returned.

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres for one would flat out refuse to run that statement because you are trying to compare apples to oranges (strings with numbers)

Comment: [Works fine in sqlite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=992e224a65cc3068e1254803f6cc67d4); Yay dynamic typing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use MySQL

Comment: Seems to work in MySQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a421aba7b1b3a49001e7bc58cb1df950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as data is varchar column so quote them as a like string

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE data NOT IN ('4','5','7')
```